# Spring Transaction Management to rollback the checked exception

Tags: spring

i am working on the Spring "@Transactional" Annotation to handle the transaction.

```
   @Transactional(readOnly = false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED,rollbackFor=SQLException.class)
public void updateBatch(Report a)
        throws SQLException, DataAccessException { insert1();insert2(); insert3(); }
```

But in case

- insert1()   -  successfully inserts the data in table A.
- insert2()   -  successfully inserts the data in table b
- insert3() -    throws the checked exception and does not insert data in table C

these inserts are ibatis inbuild functions to trigger the insert in DB
I got the following exception

```
"Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:717)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)"
```

And the transaction would not get rolledback i.e. insert1(),insert2() does not get rollback

Please do let me know what i am missing

Comment: You are getting this error b/c Spring is trying to commit a transaction that one of your methods flagged as "rollback".  Did you annotate the insert methods with Transactional too?

Comment: Actually insert1() ,insert2(),insert3() are ibatis function which are simply inserting the data in tables like `sqlMapper.insert("insertAccount", account);`

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing in insert1 and insert2?

Are they using another transaction with `PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW` attribute? If yes, they will not be rolled back. Else are you rolling back in insert1 or insert2?

I've experienced the same problem. Though it might be a bit different as the one you have. What I've had was a situation where you've got two services A and B.

A is calling a method of B in a try-catch block. B throws RuntimeException and the catch block of A wraps that exception into a catched exception.

What happened in my scenario:
- B is a separate class behind a transaction proxy
- B throws a runtime exception which sets transaction to rollback
- as I have Propagation.REQUIERED, it is the same transaction as the one for the method of A
- A wraps the exception and throws it as the exception is neither RuntimeException nor Error, the mention method will not proceed into transactionManager.rollback but to transactionManager.commit 
- that would throw the UnexpectedRollback as the transaction was previously marked as rollback.

Your case might be different.

Comment: Actually insert1() ,insert2(),insert3() are ibatis function which are simply inserting the data in tables and i read your scenario so at the end were you be able to rollback the transaction triggered bcz of checekd exception

Comment: In the given scenario, B rolls-back but A doesn't which throws UnexpectedRollBackException.

Comment: As already asked, are you putting Transactional over insert methods? If yes, with what PROPAGATION?